# Show history from all devices in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, history

I have Chrome set up to sync history between my devices

- work PC
- home PC
- laptop
- Android phone

Pulling up the history on any of these shows only the history for that specific device, but it also shows the last-opened tabs on each of the *other* devices. Is there a way to set Chrome to show **all** of my history across all devices when I open up history on any of the devices?

I have Chrome 39.0.2171.71 on the three PCs and the latest Chrome app on my phone.

Answer (score 13):

Update: One workaround is to use Google - my activity https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity which keeps track of all of my activity across several devices.
However, it is not exactly the same.

Comment: This no longer appears to work

Comment: True. This has changed, now it automatically redirects to https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity which still gives some useful information but not quite the same

Answer (score 6):

https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=6

product=6 is **chrome activity** ,

https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=1

product=1 is **android app access activity**

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser Max. Please [edit] your answer and explain with some word more what do you mean. Note: I tried your link but it doesn't work on my account/computer...

Answer (score 0):

I created a google account only to answer this further, although last post is 3 years + months old and counting.

I figured out an "easier", different way.

Over the three dots option in the right corner of Google Chrome, there has always been the option to view the Recent Tabs. It may or may not be the case that with recent updates, Google might have added the option to view multiple devices. I have 3 androids cellphone, use 1 Android emulator, and the Chrome over a Windows 10 computer.

I think that is brand new. Probably around the ver. 98 release (I have no way to prove this), since I am pretty sure years ago that option did not existed, or I never saw it. Of course you would have to log in with your google account and have the SYNC option with all or most options turned on for that to work, show up.

Again years old post, but I happened to just found it, hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think he means:

1. goto history.google.com (now at https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity)
2. up near top center click "Filter by date & product"
3. in the list of check boxes, enabling individual boxes takes you to pages that are identified by the URL appendage "product=1,"
4. where, for example, product=1 is when you have enabled Android in the "Filter by Google product" list.

Most people would just select a checkbox, not edit the URL Product parameter, but it can be done both ways.

If you do not have an Android device, the 'product=1' link may not work for you.

All this does not get you to your wished for "device," because 'product' means 'app,' not device.

I too want to see Chrome history for all my devices, whether that device is signed in or not. I used to be able to do this via +h, but then Chrome de-featured and just showed me 'logged in devices,' and now since a subsequent de-featuring, that no longer includes my Android device. I can see my Android history via the above steps, but what a PITA.  I still have no way to see PC #1's history while I am using my PC #2  if my PC #1 is in sleep-mode. While PC #1's history *may* be in https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity under the Chrome filter (URL tail is "'product=6"), I cannot obtain any device info the history as displayed in MyActivity. FML. and FG2.

Comment: Answers should stand by themselfs.  "I think he means" is a confusing statement, since you don't indicate who "he" is, nor indicated what they said.  So this answer just reads more like commentary on what somebody said, even if it might be more then that, without context its difficult to read.