# How to understand which history belongs to which device

Tags: google-chrome, sync, history

I have one gmail account. This account is used by my mobile Android, my home desktop PC and my laptop PC.

Only home desktop has history sync. Others don't have. So when I open history on mobile and laptop, they only show local history.

But when I use those [advices](https://superuser.com/questions/849040/show-history-from-all-devices-in-chrome)

I make all history sync across devices. But I can't see which history belongs to which device.

Any solution?

Or disabling history sycn on those and using 3 . partu?

Comment: "Any solution?" - Google doesn't seperate this information unless you view the accounts activity.

Comment: @Ramhound what do yoıu meant account acıtıvty, you mean here `https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols?utm_source=my-activity&utm_medium=home&utm_campaign&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyactivity.google.com%2Fmyactivity%3Fmin%3D1498078800000000%26max%3D1498769999999999%26product%3D19%26utm_campaign%3Dcontinue` i also could not find here

Comment: Links were provided in the answers to the question you linked to.

Comment: `https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=6` and `https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=1`

Comment: 'https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity' i go here.  i filter search but then i cant see any filter to seperate laptop android or desktop.  Those also dont retrieve anything `https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=6 and https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=1`

Comment: What is best, synicing all historty on those devices or disable on some of them